# Drive API set "Prevent viewers from downloading" checkbox using PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api, moodle

I'm working on a Moodle plugin (using the Drive API client libraries) that will allow a user to select a video file from Google Drive then present the file as an embedded link.  The steps required include setting the permission of the file to "AnyoneWithLink" so that the file will not require a login to view.

The issue is that I do not want to require using the Drive application to set the "Prevent viewers from downloading" flag to On.  It looks like the relevant piece of Metadata from the files section of Drive API documentation is the "copyable" attribute.  However this attribute is not writable.

Any suggestions as to how this could be done?

Right now my permission function is as follows:

```
public function change_permission($id){
    $obj = new Google_Permission();
    $obj->setid('anyoneWithLink');
    $obj->setrole('reader');
    $obj->settype('anyone');
    $obj->setWithLink(TRUE);
    try {
        $res = $this->service->permissions->insert($id, $obj);
        return $res;
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        //print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
        return null;
      }
    return NULL;
}
```

I'd like to alter the Download flag similarly to the way that the permissions are altered but I cannot find a function that has access to that attribute.

Comment: Looking like labels.restricted is the setting.  Will investigate more.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right way. Look at this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/apiDriveService.php?r=418). you will probably have an idea of how to set this label. There is setLabels(labels) method in PHP client library.